# lispworks fli: cannot be converted to foreign type

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ffi, lispworks

I wanted to add a listbox based on the sample A here below.
[The Common Lisp Cookbook - Using the Win32 API](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/win32.html)

I added a function, sendmessage which maps to its windows API counter part and call it from the wndproc.
But it complained type conversion error like below.

```
CL-USER 1 > (create-toplevel-window "ppp")

Error: #<Pointer to type (:UNSIGNED :SHORT) = #x01E902D8> cannot be
converted to foreign type (:UNSIGNED-INTEGER-TYPE 32).
```

Here are the functions related to the error. Any idea to fix the issue?
I tried to define sendmessage with **lparam** as **(:unsigned :short)** but no use.

```
(fli:define-foreign-function
    (SendMessage "SendMessage" :dbcs)
 ((hwnd hwnd) (msg uint) (wparam ulong) (lparam (:unsigned :long)))
    :result-type ulong :calling-convention :stdcall)


(fli:define-foreign-callable 
    (wndproc :result-type :long :calling-convention :stdcall)
    ((hwnd hwnd) (msg (:unsigned :long)) 
     (wparam (:unsigned :long)) (lparam (:unsigned :long)))
  (case msg
   (#.WM_CREATE
    (fli:with-foreign-string ;; class name pointer
      (cn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "LISTBOX"
     (fli:with-foreign-string ;; window name pointer
      (wn-p ec bc :external-format (external-format)) ""
      (let ((lstbx (createwindowex hwnd cn-p wn-p 
                         (logior ws_visible ws_child lbs_notify)
                cw_usedefault cw_usedefault cw_usedefault cw_usedefault
                0 0 200 100)))
    (fli:with-foreign-string (msg ec bc :external-format (external-format)) "item1"
                 (sendmessage lstbx LB_ADDSTRING 0 msg ))))))
              ;;0 0 (GetModuleHandle-current 0) 0))))

    ;;(createwindowex "listbox4test" hwnd))
   ;;(#.WM_PAINT (wndproc-paint hwnd msg wparam lparam))
   #+console (#.WM_DESTROY (PostQuitMessage 0) 0)
   (t (DefWindowProc hwnd msg wparam lparam))))
```

Comment: Just want to share that if I declare lparam in sendmessage function as :pointer (not :unsinged :long above) , it does not complain.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sendmessage function as below.
And this time, it did not complain.

```
(fli:define-foreign-function
    (SendMessage "SendMessage" :dbcs)
 ((hwnd hwnd) (msg uint) (wparam ulong) (lparam :pointer)) ;;;(lparam (:unsigned :long)))
    :result-type ulong :calling-convention :stdcall)
```